# Quotient space is compact or not

Tags: general-topology, compactness, quotient-spaces

I would like to check whether the quotient space is compact or not.
I know compact space's quotient space is also compact because projection map is continuous.
But, what about the quotient space which is not compact?

I would like to formally **prove the following cases** ($\mathbb{R}$'s topology is usual Euclid topology here).

> **$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is compact**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ which *is* compact.

Comment: @Kapil That doesn't look too relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general result asserting that if $G$ is topological group and $H$ is a dense subgroup, then $G/H$ has the trivial topology, i.e. the only open sets are the empty set and $G/H$ itself. Thus, $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ has a trivial topology. In particular, it is compact.

For a proof of the above general result, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226618/show-that-g-h-has-the-trivial-topology-if-h-subset-g-is-dense).